# Auto Gain control circuit idea

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, audio

I am trying to make an Auto Gain control circuit.

Having any input source's voltage the same.

For example my latop outputs around 1.36Vrms @ 1khz
and my iPhone outputs around 0.962Vrms @ 1khz

Regardless of input source I want the input voltage to be around the same as the laptops.

The idea is convert the input signal into a DC signal to essentially map it out. Compare the DC signal the Vref ~=500mV. The comparator will output from 0V to 1V, depending on that it will turn on the respective transistor. One transistor will be a voltage follower and will not doing anything if (V+ > V-) and if (V- > V+) then it will go to the respective transistor and go through an active op amp with a negative feedback containing a digital pot controlled by an ardunio. Using the negative feedback equation the arduino will calculate a value for the R2 resistor (Digital pot) and make it so the voltage will become 1.32Vrms using the equation R2/R1 + 1.

1 - I am not sure if this will work due to how an audio signal isn't a constant amplitude.

2 - For the full bridge rectifier since the voltage of the iphone out is already so small, I believe the Forward Voltage drop of the diode will ruin the idea of it.

3- Is this even possible?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDbW12.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Possible but distorted by compression noise. A suitable attack/decay times low pass filter must be selected using an OTA to control gain with a Vref for Vpeal

Comment: Glad is possible, however I am still worried about the full bridge rectifier, if the voltage drop is lets say ~1.4V how would that work out?

0.962V * sqrt(2) = 1.36 -1.4 = -0.04? so I guess zero volts at the output?

Comment: They used to make AGC circuits before there were Arduinos and digital potentiometers.  Maybe take a look around and see if you can locate an old circuit.

Comment: A bridge rectifier is probably not a good way.  What you'd want is more like an "ideal diode" made from a regular diode and an opamp.

Comment: Ahh like a precision rectifier circuit? Oh I have tried looking for one can't really find any that explains it well sadly.

Comment: One generally prefers a precision rectifier circuit to control an OTA with faster slew rate to reduce gain than restore gain similar to S curve compression in Audacity.exe

Comment: That fixes the Full Bridge rectifier problem, however how about how the output of the source isn't a constant amplitude? Wouldn't that affect things as well? 1kz = 500mV 10kHz 0.9V etc etc.. But I guess that doesnt matter actually?

Comment: You've asked 7 questions now and despite being tipped-off about taking the tour (and the benefit of accepting good answers) you still appear to be ignorant of this. [Take the tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour). Now you may not see the benefit but not doing the right thing makes people less inclined to help you.

Comment: @Andyaka
I'll keep this short. 

You're being a dick. You're assuming I am ignorant. I just figured out you can click the check mark instead of up voting (Thought thats how you did it) You're tour thing that you keep spamming doesn't tell how you how to actually accept an answer. I would suggest to not come onto people's question and talk about something off topic. Even the tour says stay focus and talk about the question, so Ill leave a link for you big guy. [Take the tour.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour). I feel heavily disrespected by you as you don't know the full situation.

Comment: I'm pleased to have helped you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this, the right way is to use a log rectifier, and a VCA with a mv/dB response. Parts like SSM2020 have both these (twice in fact, for stereo) on a single chip. (It's obsolete now but you can still find them, or maybe there is a more modern equivalent. The datasheet is well worth studying, it shows a number of excellent gain control applications.)

But you are right to be concerned about dynamics of the music. Any which way, you will lose some of that (depending on the time constants in your circuit). AGC circuits are inherently unsatisfactory in this way (although much modern music has been compressed quite excessively).

For the problem you describe, it would be a simpler and better solution to simply have a "PAD" switch, to slightly attenuate the laptop. You switch in a potential divider with an attenuation of about 0.7 when the laptop is in circuit. I assume both outputs are capable of driving headphones : if so, you could use values of, say, 100R and 200R; the output will see 300R, and the following amplifier will be driven by an impedance of less than 100R, which should be fine.

Comment: Are a log rectifier and a precision rectifier the same thing? The SSM2020 looks interesting thanks for the heads up. 

Oh you're right that's infinity much simpler, but you know I like over complicating things, and having it be automatic is kinda cool...

Comment: A log rectifier is similar to a precision rectifier, but the response is log not linear. If you have an interest in dynamics processing, read through and maybe try out some of the sample applications in the 2020 datasheet.